# ubuntu npm install not installing dependencies or dev dependencies

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I have cloned a project's repo (that was made on a mac) down to my ubuntu machine and I hit a lot of problems getting node to work. I feel like I'm at the final hurdle.

I can't get `npm install` to install dependencies according to the package.json file.

Note in the following, I have used `<repo description>`, `<repo name>` and `<app name>`, where appropriate, for privacy.

package.json (git repo name removed for privacy):

```
{
  "name": "<repo name>",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "npm": "2.1.x"
  },
  "description": "<repo description>",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/<repo name>"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/<repo name>/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/<repo name>#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "protractor": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.5.2",
    "ejs": "^2.3.4",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "http-server": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  }
}
```

When running `npm install`, I get:

```
npm WARN package.json <app name>@1.0.0 No README data

> <app name>@1.0.0 postinstall /home/andrew/projects/<app name>
> bower install

andrew:<app name>$
```

When running `sudo npm install`, I get:

```
npm WARN package.json <app name>@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN cannot run in wd <app name>@1.0.0 bower install (wd=/home/andrew/projects/<app name>)
```

`node -v` returns `v0.12.7`, `nodejs -v` returns `v0.10.25`, `npm -v` returns `2.12.1`, `bower -v` returns `1.5.2`, but `grunt -v` returns:

```
No command 'grunt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'grun' from package 'grun' (universe)
grunt: command not found
```

(just proof that grunt has not been installed as it should).

Comment: install `grunt-cli -g` for grunt command. did you check `./node_modules` directory?

Comment: shouldn't `npm install` install grunt for me, since it's in the package.json file's dependencies?